# Let blogs terminate in Developer Story

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-jobs, developer-story

I'd like to be able to define an end date for blogs. Why? Because I have written blogs for companies I no longer work for.

It may also happen for private blogs, e.g. you might blog about Android and then stop doing that because your Galaxy Note 7 goes up in flames.

Comment: I haven't tried this yet, but when I clicked on "Add New Item" and selected "Blogs or Videos", it asked me for a specific date (along with a title, URL, and summary). I'm guessing the date is a date of posting. A blog post is a specific instance in time, not something that runs. I don't think the intention is to highlight that you've started a blog, but to highlight specific and individual posts that were made anywhere (except for Stack Exchange answers - those have their own Top Answer category).

Comment: Valid point. Not just in these stories but worldwide.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The purpose of the blog/video item is to link to a *specific* blog post or video, either one you've authored or one that is about you or your software.

If you want to highlight that you maintained a blog for a given window of time, you should either add it to the relevant job, or post it *as a job*, ie, "Maintainer of Blog X from 1999 to 2003".

Comment: It is called "add blog", not "add blog post"

Comment: @ThomasWeller I can't see where you're finding "add blog". The only thing I see relevant to blogs is the "Blogs/Videos" item, and adding one asks for the "Link to blog post, video, presentation...". Regardless, the intent definitely seems to be to link to a *specific* post about you or written by you. If you want to link to an entire blog because you maintained it or authored it for a given window of time, there is no reason you have to use the "blogs/videos" item. Post it as a job, which is semantically the best option anyways.

Comment: I think I'll delete my blogs instead. The text on the current page is "Add blogs or videos". I can't provide any evidence that it was also called "blog" on the old page.